# Does Hibernate support mix entity mode at runtime?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Just wondering does Hibernate supports combination of static properties and dynamic properties in an entity. For example

```
public class User
{  
  private Long id;  
  private String first_name;  
  private String last_name;  
  private Map<String,Object> dynamicProperties;  
}
```

I can get the dynamic properties by reading the metadata of User table from Db at runtime. 
Basically I am working on a product which is supporting multiple client.

For one client User table can have columns like `id`, `first_name`, `last_name` only whereas for another client user table need to store two addition columns like `DOB` and `Title`.

Considering `id`, `first_name` and `last_name` as common set of properties among all clients I am using those as  static properties and rest I am planning to store as a map in the entity. Not sure dies hibernate support this.

Constraint is that code knows about dynamic properties column at runtime only.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mapping strategy needs to be looked at. In hibernate you want your schema static. I would suggest renaming dynamicProperties to metaData and make the map to have string key and string value then include that as a mapped property in your hibernate mapping file. Having a map of generic object values in hibernate that is mapped does not make sense. The other alternative would be to mark that map as @transient but I think the first suggestion makes more sense. You want metadata that is client specific so map it as part of your schema.

Comment: This is the part of your question I did not understand "Constraint is that code knows about dynamic properties column at runtime only", to me that seems like a transient property don't see why you need that constraint

Comment: Thanks Duncan.Let me explain my question little bit further. I am working on a product which supports multiple organization as a client. Definition of an employee for one organization can have 3 fields like id, firstName, lastName whereas for other organization it can have 5 fields like id, firstName,lastName,Date of Birth, Salutation so on. To support these variations I am using common attributes of Employee as properties of Object and client specific attributes stored in the map named as dynamicProperties. So basically whenever a new client comes in the code will read the metadata from db.

Comment: Explain more on "metadata from db" you are sticking to one schema for all clients right? What about a object like CustomProperty that has an id and a string value and a constant for the data type that can be casted in runtime. Then I suppose you could write a custom query method for that metadata. But each client will have the same schema right?

Comment: nope. Actually my middleware is going to support the different schema for different clients using spearate DB instance for each client to avoid data mixing. Consider at one moment my middleware application is supporting client A using mysql Db with baisc schema and after 10 days we are planning to bring another client B on board having Oracle DB with extension schema. Look my previous comment for what do I mean by extended schema. so basically there schemas are different marginally on basic entity level.

Comment: That sounds scary, there has to be a way to keep one schema for all clients and accommodate the meta-data in the schema. You're going end up with all these different schema and down the road with a 100 clients yikes!

Answer (score 0):

The project I'm working on does exactly this (dynamic, per-client models). However, we don't try to mix static (class-based) and dynamic entities on the same row. You can easily do what you want by separating the static part of your model from the dynamic part and map the static with classes and the dynamic part with EntityMode.MAP entites. I've submitted a [patch for Hibernate 4.1](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/455) that allows you to use JPA criteria queries with EntityMode.MAP. This makes dynamic query generation much simpler.